# Highlight mobile phone numbers?

Tags: cti

We have a Twilio system set up to send texts from Salesforce.  Right now we are relying on class names and header names to identify mobile numbers. Very brittle and hackish. I have been researching a [Open CTI](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cloud_cti_api_overview.htm&language=en_US) solution, but I can't find mentions of mobile numbers.

Is it possible to select and interact with mobile numbers using the CTI Toolkit? Is there a different way we could highlight mobile numbers and add functionality to them?